# order Plotly Bar chart w.r.t Y axes / By the height of the bar

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to sort the bar chart w.r.t to the values on Y axis, like show tallest bar first, and then the second tallest etc.

Say, I have Product and Sales data:

```
> Product <- c("Orange", "Mango", "Apple")
> Sale <- c(28, 50, 21)
> data <- data.frame(Product, Sale)
> plot_ly(data, x = ~Product, y = ~Sale, type = 'bar')
```

This shows me bars with the order of `Apple, Mango & Orange`. what I need is the order: `Mango, Orange & Apple`. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your factor levels in the correct order. In your case you can order the data.frame by Sale and then set the factor level as they appear in the current form:

```
library(tidyverse)

Product <- c("Orange", "Mango", "Apple")
Sale <- c(28, 50, 21)
data <- data.frame(Product, Sale) %>%
  arrange(-Sale) %>%
  mutate(Product = fct_inorder(Product))

plot_ly(data, x = ~Product, y = ~Sale, type = 'bar')
```

The relevant function `fct_inorder()` is from the **forcats** package.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply change your plot_ly function to

```
plot_ly(data, x = stats::reorder(Product, -Sale), y = ~Sale, type = 'bar')
```

This should work